# How to remove characters between the first occurrences of an expression?

Tags: python, regex

I'll explain what I want using an example. I'm working with DNA sequences. Let's say I want to remove everything between `GUA` and `CAG`(including `GUA` and `CAG`) in a string. So if the input is : `"AAAAGUAGGGGCAGCAGUUUUUGUAAAAACAG"`

The output should be : `["AAAA","CAGUUUUU"]`. I initially used `re.split(r'GUA\w*CAG',a)`, but that returns `["AAAA"]`. It seems to look for the last occurrence of `CAG` in the string instead of the first occurrence.

Comment: What should happen with `AAAGUAGGGGUAUUUCAG`? Should the first or the second `GUA` count? Also, shouldn't you make sure that the number of bases between the two markers is divisible by 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex, by default `*`, `+` and `?` are [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

If you don't want that behavior, use their non-greedy counterparts  `*?`, `+?` and `??`:

```
re.split(r'GUA\w*?CAG',a)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: you need to trim out the empty string in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a quantifier `?` and also it's better to use `.*?` instead `\w*?` because `\w` matches only the word charcters.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "AAAAGUAGGGGCAGCAGUUUUUGUAAAAACAG"
>>> m = re.split(r'GUA.*?CAG', s)
>>> m
['AAAA', 'CAGUUUUU', '']
>>> [x for x in m if x]
['AAAA', 'CAGUUUUU']
```